# MPMoviewviewcontroller did not stream?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am using MPMoviewviewcontroller example Movieplayer,when i give apple's sample URL
[streaming](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbopgear1.html) in stream tab, it did not give output? any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that it is because you're accessing an html page and the movieplayer may be expecting an m3u8 (HTTP Live Streaming)?

Try with a direct link to a video/playlist, even if it means a progressive download, but MPMoviePlayerController does indeed stream.